# How to set style at WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, styles

I have this code and it works:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="15,50,0,25" Grid.Row="8" MouseLeftButtonDown="buttonFermaNAO_Click">
<Image Margin="0,10,0,10"
      Width="206" Height="46" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto_esegui_senza scritta_ROLL_OFF.png"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto start_senza scritta_Roll_ON.png"/>
        </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Roboto-Bold"
   FontSize="25" Foreground="White" >Ferma NAO</Label>
</Grid>
```

With this code when I move the mouse over the image the image is changed and it is ok but in the center of the image I have the Label, and I i move the mouse on the Label the image is not changed and it is not ok.

I though if is possible to delete the image code and set the style at grid, it's possible this?

This is the result that I have now:

[image]

if I move the mouse over the button I have this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with a DataTrigger bound to your Grids IsMouseOver Property:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
Margin="15,50,0,25" Grid.Row="8" x:Name="myGrid" MouseLeftButtonDown="buttonFermaNAO_Click">
    <Image Margin="0,10,0,10"
  Width="206" Height="46" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto_esegui_senza scritta_ROLL_OFF.png"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=myGrid}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto start_senza scritta_Roll_ON.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Roboto-Bold"
      FontSize="25" Foreground="White" >Ferma NAO</Label>
</Grid>
```